# Error while pushing values to blade template in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

My code is

```
public function listCompanies()
{
    $companyObj = new company();
    $companies = $companyObj->getCompanies();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main',['companies'=>$companies]);
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
ErrorException
Creating default object from empty value
```

The error line is

```
$this->layout->content = View::make('admin/main',['companies'=>$companies]);
```

Comment: Your environment may have E_STRICT warnings enabled in error_reporting if it is PHP 5.3 or less, or E_WARNING with PHP 5.4+.
That error is triggered when $layout is NULL

Answer (score 0):

Set a:

```
protected $layout = 'your_layout_name';
```